# Passing JSON string to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, function, parameter-passing

I'm working on a project, and we use a lot of coding languages for different parts.

I've tried to simplify the problem as much as I can, and came up with the following
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0x9p6d7/6/).

The problem is, I have a JSON string which I want to pass on to a JavaScript function.
If I call it from JavaScript, it's OK. But when I call it with a `onmouseover`, HTML throws the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

#### JavaScript Code:

```js
 function test123(obj, e, lookupx){
      console.log(lookupx);
    }

    test123(this, event, '{"mt:assetsys:assetuapr":{"assetmat":"material","assettag":"tag"}}');
```

#### HTML:

```html
    <div>
      First check the console, direct calling with js string is ok.<br>
      Then:<br>
      <a href="#" onmouseover="test123(this, event, '{"mt:assetsys:assetuapr": 
                 {"assetmat":"material","assettag":"tag"}}');">hover this
      </a>
      <br>
      And an error occurs
    </div>
```

Could someone explain what the difference is between the two cases?

1. The onmouseover **vs**
2. The direct calling to the function.

Comment: Escape the inner `"`, e.g. `\"`

Comment: because in the second case the JSON string is wrapped inside double-quotes already (for the onmouseover attribute), so you need to escape the double-quotes in the JSON, otherwise the onmouseover attribute will be malformed - the first time it comes to a double-quote related to the JSON it thinks it's the end of the onmouseover attribute, but it's not.

Comment: Of course, thank you both for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had the same scenario, I ended up using [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Note, you have to use single quotes `'` for HTML attribute value.

So your code can be re-written as follows,

```
<div>
  First check the console, direct calling with js string is ok.<br>
  Then:<br>
  <a href="#" onmouseover='test123(this, event, `{"mt:assetsys:assetuapr":{"assetmat":"material","assettag":"tag"}}`);'>
   hover this
  </a><br>
  And an error occurs
</div>
```

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0x9p6d7/57/)

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! In my honest opinion, the readability of this answer is much better than when you escape them (like in the other answers). Ty for the link to template literal.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape all the quotes inside the onmousover=""

Escape them with a backslash like this \"

Comment: Silly me, I can do that of course. The answer Gaurav Gandhi gave is slightly more readable. But thank you none the less!

Answer (score 1):

You are not escaping the character, also you need to make some adjustment like I did for your [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0x9p6d7/53/)

Check it , it works fine

**HTML**

```
<div>
  First check the console, direct calling with js string is ok.<br>
  Then:<br>
  <a href="#" onmouseover='test123(this, event, "{\"mt:assetsys:assetuapr\":{\"assetmat\":\"material\",\"assettag\":\"tag\"}}")'>
   hover this
  </a><br>
  And an error occurs
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function test123(obj, e, lookupx){
 console.log(lookupx);
}

test123(this, event, '{"mt:assetsys:assetuapr":{"assetmat":"material","assettag":"tag"}}');
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it cleared a few things up. The code isn't working 100%, but I get the gist :)

Comment: but it is working , i checked in myself in the console. :)

Comment: Well, I'll be... I'm sorry, your JSFiddle works indeed. Yet when I copy and paste the code given in your 2 blocks (HTML and JS) and paste it in JSFiddle myself, it returns: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: test123 is not defined'. But I can't, for the life of me, spot the difference.. Strange, but nevertheless, thank you :)

Comment: may be you need to select , No wrap - bottom of <head>, in JS load type